# Is it useless to declare a local variable as rvalue-reference, e.g. T&& r = move(v)?

Tags: c++, c++11, scope, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

Could you guys give me an illustrative example under certain circumstance to prove the following statements are useful and necessary?

```
AnyTypeMovable   v;
AnyTypeMovable&& r = move(v);
```

Comment: I'd say it's rather useless since `r` is now an lvalue (it has a name!), and you need `std::move(r)` anyway to make it an rvalue.

Comment: Fun fact: `v` doesn't need to be movable.

Comment: Fun fact: there is no move happening in this code.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's 100% useless, you could use it to tell people reading the code next that this variable is a temporary and it will be moved, though I suppose in general it's easy to spot when `std::move` is called anyway

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Devils Advocate

Answer (score 16):

No, `AnyTypeMovable&& r = move(v);` here is not useful at all.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class MyMovableType
{
        int i;
public:
        MyMovableType(int val): i(val){}
        MyMovableType(MyMovableType&& r) { this->i = r.i; r.i = -1; }
        MyMovableType(const MyMovableType& r){ this->i = r.i; }
        int getVal(){ return i; }
};

int main()
{
        std::vector<MyMovableType> vec;
        MyMovableType a(10);
        MyMovableType&& aa = std::move(a);

        vec.push_back(aa);

        std::cout << a.getVal() << std::endl;

        return 0;

}
```

As `aa` is an l-value (as noted by [R. Martinho Fernandes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46642/r-martinho-fernandes),  and also by [Xeo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500104/xeo) - *a named rvalue-reference is an lvalue*), this will print `10` indicating that **moving has not been performed** (nor in the assignment, nor in the `push_back` call), so you still need to `std::move` it to the `push_back` method, as in this case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class MyMovableType
{
        int i;
public:
        MyMovableType(int val): i(val){}
        MyMovableType(MyMovableType&& r) { this->i = r.i; r.i = -1; }
        MyMovableType(const MyMovableType& r){ this->i = r.i; }
        int getVal(){ return i; }
};

int main()
{
        std::vector<MyMovableType> vec;
        MyMovableType a(10);
        MyMovableType&& aa = std::move(a);

        vec.push_back(std::move(aa));

        std::cout << a.getVal() << std::endl;

        return 0;

}
```

move will be performed, so the printout will be `-1`. So, despite the fact that you're passing `aa` to the `push_back`, you still need to pass it via `std::move`.

Comment: So in this context `std::string&&` is just the same as `std::string&`? Is this how the standart defines it?

Comment: @Haatschii: Yes, a named rvalue-references is an lvalue.

Comment: The first test is inconclusive, btw. Moving a `std::string` doesn't require the original string to be left in any particular state. It only has to be valid, and it's perfectly fine for it to have the same original value.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes You're right, I will write a simple class instead.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, Named rvalue is lvalue. So you should use std::forward.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class MyMovableType
{
        int i;
public:
        MyMovableType(int val)  noexcept   : i(val){}
        MyMovableType(MyMovableType&& r) noexcept { this->i = r.i; r.i = -1; }
        MyMovableType(const MyMovableType& r) noexcept{ this->i = r.i; }
        int getVal()const noexcept{ return i; }
};

int main()
{
        std::vector<MyMovableType> vec;
        MyMovableType a(10);
        MyMovableType&& aa = std::move(a);

        vec.push_back( std::forward<decltype(a)>(aa) );

        std::cout << a.getVal() << std::endl; // -1 printed.

        return 0;

}
```

Comment: If I understand right, the std::forward call here will do the same thing that std::move would do (that is, it will finally move the aa that was not yet moved by the preceding call to std::move)--yet nonetheless std::forward should not be used here, because its purpose is to "forward" type information that is unknown in the scope of the std::forward call, and said info is NOT unknown here (i.e., we know all about the type of aa). (NB - I have only just learned about this stuff and am mainly parroting Scott Myers:  http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2012/11/on-superfluousness-of-stdmove.html )

Comment: yeah, keep std::forward for proper argument forwarding, not move semantic