# Why does rvalue reference argument prefer const lvalue reference to rvalue reference parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, rvalue-reference

Here is some code in VS2015:

```
class Elem 
{
public:
    Elem(int i) : a(i) {}
    Elem(Elem && other) = default;
    Elem(const Elem & other) = default;
private:
    int a;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Elem> vv;

    // case 0
    vv.push_back(Elem{ 0 }); // call push_back(Elem &&);

    // case 1
    Elem e1{ 1 };
    vv.push_back(e1); // call push_back(const Elem &);

    // case 2
    Elem e2{ 2 };
    auto & lref = e2;
    vv.push_back(lref); // call push_back(const Elem &);

    // case 3
    Elem e3{ 3 };
    auto && rref = std::move(e3);
    vv.push_back(rref); // call push_back(const Elem &);

    // case 4
    Elem e4{ 4 };
    vv.push_back(std::move(e4)); // call push_back(Elem &&);

    return 0;
}
```

In case 3, the type of `rref` is rvalue reference, and its value category is `lvalue`, and calls `push_back(const Elem &)`.

In case 4, According to Effective Modern C++ Item 23, an implementation of `std::move` is something like

```
// C++ 14    
template<typename T>
decltype(auto) move(T&& param)
{
    using ReturnType = remove_reference_t<T>&&;
    return static_cast<ReturnType>(param);
}
```

The type of `std::move(e4)` is `Elem &&`, and its value category is `prvalue`, calls `push_back(Elem &&)`.

So a `lvalue` of `T&&` matches `const T &`, and a `prvalue` of `T&&` matches `T&&`, what do type and value category of an expression actually do during overload resolution between `T`, `const T &` and `T &&`?

---

Sorry for not describing my problem clearly. As so many links said that, if an argument's value category is `prvalue`, the function with `T&&` will be called; value category is `lvalue`, the function with `const T &` will be called.

Can I simply say that argument's type is used for overload resolution, while value category is checked for reference binding when parameter's type is a reference?

Comment: As soon as your variable has name it's an lvalue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18766736/390913

Answer (score 1):

`rref` is an lvalue since it has a name, so `push_back(const Elem &)` is called. The `move` into a named variable is useless, but if you insist on it you can change your code to:

```
// case 3
Elem e3{ 3 };
auto && rref = std::move(e3);
vv.push_back(std::forward<decltype(e3)>(rref));
```

And then `push_back(Elem &&)` is called. Or just do what you did in case 4.

Answer (score 0):

The moment when u assign a variable name(in this case "e3"), and use this variable to pass in the function it becomes lvalue. That's why its calling the lvalue version of function "push_back". But when u are passing as "std::move(e4)" in Case 4, it is passed as rvalue and that's why its calling the rvalue reference version of "push_back" function.

just going through the web i found this link which explains rvalue reference in almost similar terms. u can check this link.

http://simpletechtalks.com/rvalue-references/